# How do you delete an Azure blob created in resource manager with powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

There is an Remove-AzureStorageBlob command.  But no equivalent Remove-AzureRMStorageBlob command.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, there is no command Remove-AzureRMStorageBlob, in ARM PowerShell, we still use **Remove-AzureStorageBlob** command, here is my test:

```
PS > $rg = "jason"
PS > $sn = "jason999"
PS > $con = "jason"
PS > $key = "5RPye6dEett3ZwWPr+JuB3FVx59dmfOXq/NfvgFlUNAiBjoKkm3w+Yu5w/x6Hmxg6aOYDGrOuxOlXzQZ1hViLQ=="
PS > $ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $sn -StorageAccountKey $key
PS > $ctx


StorageAccountName : jason999
BlobEndPoint       : https://jason999.blob.core.windows.net/
TableEndPoint      : https://jason999.table.core.windows.net/
QueueEndPoint      : https://jason999.queue.core.windows.net/
FileEndPoint       : https://jason999.file.core.windows.net/
Context            : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext
Name               :
StorageAccount     : BlobEndpoint=https://jason999.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://jason999.queue.core.win
                     dows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://jason999.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://jason999.fil
                     e.core.windows.net/;AccountName=jason999;AccountKey=[key hidden]
EndPointSuffix     : core.windows.net/



PS > Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob * -Container $con -Context $ctx


ICloudBlob        : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob
BlobType          : BlockBlob
Length            : 26645
ContentType       : image/png
LastModified      : 1/18/2017 12:59:11 AM +00:00
SnapshotTime      :
ContinuationToken :
Context           : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext
Name              : 113.PNG



PS > Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob * -Container $con -Context $ctx | Remove-AzureStorageBlob
PS > Get-AzureStorageBlob -Blob * -Container $con -Context $ctx
PS >
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a command named Remove-AzureRMStorageBlob because the data plane API of legacy Azure Storage account and ARM Azure Storage account is totally the same. The only difference between legacy Azure Storage account and ARM Azure Storage account is in control plane (account creation, account deletion, and account-level metadata/property management).